# Get size and location of childwindow with user32

Tags: vb.net, winapi

If I know the hwnd of a window, could I get it's position and location based on my screen size. (I mean, size and location in pixels)

What I want to do is capture the screen, but only capture the handle's area.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out GetWindowRect() and GetWindowPlacement() APIs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519(VS.85).aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633518(VS.85).aspx